# asp.net mvc post to asmx web service

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-5, asmx

I apologize if this is a stupid question.

In my `MVC` application I have to contact an external `ASMX` web service. I haven't found the info I need to get this done. I want to make a `HTTP POST` request to the web service, I have the `URL` and I know the `Content-Type` should be `application/x-www-urlencoded`.

I am supposed to provide two parameters, `SSN` and `PASSWORD`. The response is `XML` that I have to walk through and get into objects.

Does it matter if I do this inside a controller or not?

Can anyone provide an example of how to:
1. create the request,
2. walk through an XML response

Answer (score 0):

Add a servicereference in your project to the external asmx service and call it through your controller method. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) is a good example of consuming webservices